# creating a pandas dataframe from a database query that uses bind variables

Tags: python, sql, database, oracle, pandas

I'm working with an Oracle database. I can do this much:

```
    import pandas as pd
    import pandas.io.sql as psql
    import cx_Oracle as odb
    conn = odb.connect(_user +'/'+ _pass +'@'+ _dbenv)

    sqlStr = "SELECT * FROM customers"
    df = psql.frame_query(sqlStr, conn)
```

But I don't know how to handle bind variables, like so:

```
    sqlStr = """SELECT * FROM customers 
                WHERE id BETWEEN :v1 AND :v2
             """
```

I've tried these variations:

```
   params  = (1234, 5678)
   params2 = {"v1":1234, "v2":5678}

   df = psql.frame_query((sqlStr,params), conn)
   df = psql.frame_query((sqlStr,params2), conn)
   df = psql.frame_query(sqlStr,params, conn)
   df = psql.frame_query(sqlStr,params2, conn)
```

The following works:

```
   curs = conn.cursor()
   curs.execute(sqlStr, params)
   df = pd.DataFrame(curs.fetchall())
   df.columns = [rec[0] for rec in curs.description]
```

but this solution is just...inellegant. If I can, I'd like to do this without creating the cursor object. Is there a way to do the whole thing using just pandas?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `pandas.io.sql.read_sql_query`. I used pandas version 0.20.1, I used it, it worked out:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas.io.sql as psql
import cx_Oracle as odb
conn = odb.connect(_user +'/'+ _pass +'@'+ _dbenv)

sqlStr = """SELECT * FROM customers 
            WHERE id BETWEEN :v1 AND :v2
"""
pars = {"v1":1234, "v2":5678}
df = psql.frame_query(sqlStr, conn, params=pars)
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, pandas expects that the SQL string be completely formed prior to passing it along. With that in mind, I would (and always do) use string interpolation:

```
params = (1234, 5678)
sqlStr = """
SELECT * FROM customers 
WHERE id BETWEEN %d AND %d
""" % params
print(sqlStr)
```

which gives

```
SELECT * FROM customers 
WHERE id BETWEEN 1234 AND 5678
```

So that should feed into `psql.frame_query` just fine. (it does in my experience with postgres, mysql, and sql server).

Comment: I'd strongly advise against forming your SQL this way as it leaves your code vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Even if your code/database isn't in a position to be vulnerable, you shouldn't get in the practice of forming your SQL this way. Bind variables are the safe way to go.

Comment: @DavidMarx agreed. I shouldn't have assumed the OP was working from a command-line (or just a basic script) like I normally do.

Comment: [FYI: I'm OP] Yeah, this is a self-contained file. I don't foresee any real issues with SQL injection in my current program since the people who will be using it will have direct access to the database anyway, but I would like to know for the future if I can use pandas in the way I described.

Comment: Oops. I see that now. FWIW, I'm able to recreate your experience/frustration using `pyodbc` on my databases. From my perspective, the path of least resistance is to hack on pandas so that `read_frame` can take a cursor object. Maybe I'll be able to get a PR together soon.

Comment: well your `cur.fetchall()` technique covers that. i'll stop blabbering now.